# hash_hmac secret key in nodej to equivalent php code

Tags: php, node.js

I have an example in nodejs that I want to do in php

```js
    var nonce = new Date().getTime();
        
    var postdata = postdata || {};
    postdata.nonce = nonce;
        
    var stringmessage = JSON.stringify(postdata);
    var signedMessage = new hmac("sha512", self.secret);
        
    signedMessage.update(stringmessage);
        
    var sign = signedMessage.digest('hex');
```

So my code is as far as I can workout would be this

```php
    $data['nounce'] = time();
    $dataJson = json_encode($data);

    $sign = dechex(hash_hmac('sha512', $data ,$this->getSecret()));
```

but if I try to connect to this I get this message when trying to connect

```
Warning: file_get_contents(https://www.example.com.au/api/quote/buy): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
```

so I am assuming this is connecting to the hash is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Three things to change and it should work:

1. In your JavaScript you use "nonce" but in your PHP you use "nounce"
2. In your PHP hash_hmac you pass $data as the second parameter but you should be passing $dataJson
3. You don't need the dechex, hash_hmac "Returns a string containing the calculated message digest as lowercase hexits unless raw_output is set to true" from https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash-hmac.php